# Конвертация bmp изображения в матрицу и обратно c#

Tags: c#

подскажите пожалуйста как преобразовать индексы цветов изображения (хранящийся например в текстовом txt формате) в изображение. пример кода встречал на просторах рунета https://sohabr.net/habr/post/195344/ или  http://deadlock.org.ua/kit/habr/post/21221 или http://all-best-tips.com/52930-how-to-convert-rgb-images-to-text.html или http://learn-myself.com/convert-rgb-images-to-text-8319/ или http://www.pvsm.ru/programmirovanie/44259/print/  однако запустить код не удалось. в первой части - конвертация в матрицу более менее гладко но во второй - типа "обратно" но никак уж..
[image: запись в файл]

```
 это запись в файл или половина кода работоспособная:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace steamWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\x1.bmp"); // c : \ 1.bmp - адрес        изображения
            Color[,] color = new Color[bmp.Width, bmp.Height];
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    color[x, y] = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                }
            StreamWriter steamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"z:\x5.txt");
           for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                {
                    steamWriter.Write(color[x, y].R.ToString("X2"));
                    steamWriter.Write(color[x, y].G.ToString("X2"));
                   steamWriter.Write(color[x, y].B.ToString("X2") + " ");
               }
                steamWriter.WriteLine();
            }
            steamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `Bitmap.LockBits`.

Comment: Матрицу каких объектов вы хотите получить?

Comment: собственно из матрицы изображение. на картинке вы можете наблюдать результат преобразования изображения в подобие матрицы а вот обратно что - то не клеится с кодом.

Comment: это код не мой я его  выгуглил, взял всё готовое , к сожалению те кто его размножил в сети видно  драли друг у друга размножая не тока код но и ошибки. первоисточник найти мне не удалось вероятно какая то из книг еще первых лет. вот ссылки : http://deadlock.org.ua/kit/habr/post/21221   или       http://all-best-tips.com/52930-how-to-convert-rgb-images-to-text.html    или    http://learn-myself.com/convert-rgb-images-to-text-8319/

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, ссылка на СоХабр у меня не открылась почему-то, но вот рабочий код преобразования BMP в матрицу цветов выглядит так:

```
public Color[][] GetBitMapColorMatrix(string bitmapFilePath)
    {
        bitmapFilePath = @"C:\Filename.bmp";
        Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(bitmapFilePath);

        int hight = b1.Height;
        int width = b1.Width;

        Color[][] colorMatrix = new Color[width][];
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            colorMatrix[i] = new Color[hight];
            for (int j = 0; j < hight; j++)
            {
                colorMatrix[i][j] = b1.GetPixel(i, j);
            }
        }
        return colorMatrix;
    }
```

Соответственно, картинка у вас будет как двумерный массив типа `Color`, у которого есть метод `Color.ToArgb()`, возвращающий значение типа `int` и метод 'ToString()', возвращающий строковое представление.

Так вот при помощи этих методов вполне реально представить картинку в виде текстового файла, записав в него строковые или целочисленные значения матрицы.

Вот пример модифицированного метода для сохранения в файлы через `ToString()` и через `ToArgb()` соответственно:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Объявляем переменную для формирования строки первой матрицы в текстовом представлении (значения по оси Х картинки)
        string FileLine1 = string.Empty;
        //Объявляем список строк, в который будем построчно добавлять матрицу в текстовом виде
        List<string> file1 = new List<string>();

        //Объявляем переменную для формирования строки матрицы, в которую будем писать значения цветов в формате ARGB
        string FileLine2 = string.Empty;
        //Список строк для формирования второго файла
        List<string> file2 = new List<string>();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Если мы через диалог выбрали картинку, то грузим ее в битмап.
            Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            //Объявляем переменные для значений высоты и ширины матрицы (картинки)...
            //...и тут же задаем значения этих переменных взяв их из высоты и ширины картинки в пикселях
            int height = b1.Height; //Это высота картинки, и наша матрица по вертикали будет состоять из точно такого же числа элементов.
            int width = b1.Width; //Это ширина картинки, т.е. число элементов матрицы по горизонтали

            //Тут мы объявляем саму матрицу в виде двумерного массива,
            Color[,] colorMatrix = new Color[width,height];

            //Запускаем цикл, где итератором будет целочисленная переменная i, равная при начале цикла нулю.
            //Цикл будет выполняться от 0 и до тех пор, пока y меньше height (высоты матрицы и картинки)
            //На каждой итерации увеличиваем значение y на единицу.
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                //В начале каждой итерации мы обнуляем переменные для формирования строк для файлов
                FileLine1 = string.Empty;
                FileLine2 = string.Empty;
                //А теперь сканируем горизонтальные строки матрицы:
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    //В матрицу добавляем цвет точки с координатами x,y из картинки b1.            
                    colorMatrix[x,y] = b1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    //А теперь преобразуем цвет точки (x,y) в:
                    //1. Текстовое представление:
                    FileLine1 += colorMatrix[x,y].ToString() + " ";
                    //2. Значение цвета в целочисленном формате:
                    FileLine2 += colorMatrix[x,y].ToArgb().ToString() + " ";
                    //Тут в обоих случаях в конечном итоге строки преобразуются к типу string для удобства их сохранения в текстовом файле
                }
                //А теперь в списки добавляем каждую из полученных строк:
                //Строка картинки в текстовом виде:
                file1.Add(FileLine1);
                //Строка картинки в виде значения цветов пикселей
                file2.Add(FileLine2);
            }
            //Записываем полученные результаты в текстовые файлы:
            File.WriteAllLines("D:\\pic1.txt", file1);
            File.WriteAllLines("D:\\pic2.txt", file2);
        }
    }
```

Лично мне более удобным показался вариант с сохранением целочисленных значений. Потому обратный процесс написал именно для него. 
Писал весьма быстро и "в лоб", уверен, можно было сделать более оптимально:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> file = new List<string>();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            file = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToList();
            if (file.Count() < 1) return; //Файл пустой!
            var width = file[0].Split(' ').Count() - 1; //В конце строки у нас есть дополнительный пробел!
            var heigh = file.Count;

            Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(width, heigh);
            string[] s;
            for (var y = 0; y < heigh; y++)
            {
                s = file[y].TrimEnd(' ').Split(' ');
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    var i = int.Parse(s[x]);
                    Color pixel = new Color();
                    pixel = Color.FromArgb(i);
                    b2.SetPixel(x, y, pixel);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Осталось только в `unsafe` перевести, а то с пикселями работать из управляемого кода - весьма не быстрое дело.

Comment: Попиксельно работать с картинками в любом случае не быстрое дело, да еще когда пиксели представляются как строки (текстовый файл), а не числа (байты).

Comment: @Сергей, unsafe не нужен, а вот от `GetPixel` избавиться надо.

Comment: Что-то тут слишком много кода...

Comment: Для наглядности и понятности, да еще и спешил до конца рабочего дня, так рефакторить всегда есть куда ))

Comment: разъясните пожалуйста вариант 2 (пример модифицированного метода для сохранения в файлы )понятно куда пишем но непонятно откуда?

Comment: Постарался как можно более подробно прокомментировать код модифицированного метода сохранения, плюс немного изменил его, для наглядности изменив имена переменных.

Comment: чё то собирается с ошибкой... спасибо за комментарии очень кстати насколько сей метод быстрее за GetPixel?

Comment: Опечатки исправил, обновил `button1_Click` и `button2_Click`, никаких ошибок не наблюдаю уже. Насчет `GetPixel` не понял вопроса, что значит, быстрее? Тут в первом случае используется `GetPixel` для получения цвета точки (пикселя) картинки и преобразования в числовое значение цвета, а во втором — используется `SetPixel` для "рисования" точки (пикселя) картинки цветами, которые берутся из текстового файла.

Comment: прелесть. вы правы ошибка была не ваша.

Comment: на моём core2duo текстовый файлик после запуска созревает секунд десять. неясно это попиксельная обработка стока "время расходует" или генерация текстового файла из буфера?

Comment: А размер картинки какой у вас? Тут прямая зависимость скорости от размера, это раз. Во-вторых, попиксельная обработка сама по себе крайне медленная. И да, работа со строками скорости не добавляет. Так что это всё будет работать и работает, но очень медленно. В реальных приложениях (если это не курсовая, не лабораторная и т.д.) я бы вряд ли бы стал использовать такой подход.

Comment: небольшая 337на306 ,  402 килобайта .

Comment: интересно если работать с данными не выводя в файл скорость насколько повысится?

Comment: Закомментируйте всё, что связано с выводом в файл и посмотрите )